# How to disable auto-correction for excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've an issue when coding in excel-vba editor. Some classes beginning with uppercase have become lowercase for their first letter. For example:

- `Range` -> `range`
- `ThemeColor` -> `themeColor`

Here's the **example code**

```
Sub SetAltColor(source As range, themeColor As XlThemeColor, percent0 As Double, percent1 As Double)
'
' Set alternative color for rows
'
Dim i As Integer
With source
    .Font.themeColor = themeColor
    For i = 1 To source.Columns.Count
        With .Cells(1, i).Font
            If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
                .TintAndShade = percent0
            Else
                .TintAndShade = percent1
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, the 1st parameter show `range` and at line 7, you can see `.Font.themeColor` as well

**excel version**
14.0.7151.5001 (32bit)

Can someone explains what happens and how should i fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post a code example? Have you used these names as variables anywhere?

Comment: (Other Tom here) What excel/vba-Version are you using?

Comment: I'll add these things

Comment: Stop using reserved words as the name(s) of your variables and parameters.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @Merlin2001 and I'm now stop using reserved words to avoid this situation :)